# Handling h.264 Elementary Stream on Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, h.264, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

I have been trying to understand how to decode an h.264 elementary stream on Android for a while and I haven't been able to find any definitive answers. The examples on [this page](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/) are all good, but they are generating frames to decode on the fly using MediaCodec or MediaExtractor.

I am looking for a solution that enables me to decode an elementary stream (i.e from a *.264 file or over a streaming socket). I understand the basic principles of NAL units and separating them, but I'm not sure that I understand how to feed the NAL units into the decoder/extractor.

Comment: So instead of MediaCodec, what decoder do you intend to use?

Comment: I intend to use the MediaCodec, but the difference is in that I am reading from an existing stream. [This video](https://youtu.be/5mzVaWtxwos) helped a bit and now I'm just working on building a frame provider that parses the NAL units.